# missing php intl & xsl extensions while installing Magento 2 on readiness check point

Tags: php, windows, magento, mamp, intl

I'm trying to run the Magento installer on Windows 7 with MAMP 3.3.0 . When I do that *Readiness Check* says to me that: xsl & intl extension is missing. 
I have both *dll* in the `/ext` dir .

I have two *php.ini* files in `conf\php7.0.13\` dir : `php.ini-development` & `php.ini-production`. I already uncomment the xsl and intl in the both *php.ini* files.

Copied icu***.dll from php to apache bin folder too but still gets the same 
error.

Help me, please. If I have not clearly explained, what information is needed to solve the problem?
What could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're trying to make it run on Windows otherwise there is no meaning in using .dll files.

Before starting the configuration of the Magento drop a file in that configuration with

```
phpinfo();
```

and get the exact location of the used php.ini file so you'll be sure there's not a 3rd one.

Uncomment and check the location of the extensions.

Comment: 1)phpinfo() said that Loaded Configeration File is conf / php7.0.13 / php.ini 2)also that Configeration File php.ini Path is c:\Windows. This file is not there. Decided to try to add a Path to path in folder with php.ini. Phpinfo() showed that nothing has changed 3)I try to run php as an apache module by adding to "httpd.conf": the lines LoadModule php7_module "~/bin/php/php7apache2_2.dll" and PHPIniDir "~ / php / php7.0.13" . nothing. 4)add php.ini to c:\Windows, so that phpinfo() reads as it wants. nothing. And when php.ini was removed from the root, Installer began to scold all at once.

Comment: So.. Maybe this isn't correct answer to the question. But to me the answer was: 1)to install Ubuntu 2) then install LAMP 3) then install Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit `php.ini` in the php installed folder usually present in  `/etc/php`

old code

...

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

...

...

```
;extension=php_xsl.dll
```

new code

...

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

...

...

```
extension=php_xsl.dll
```

save and restart your apache.

Answer (score -1):

IN xamp/php/php.ini search and modify php.ini file and search (;extension=php_xsl.dll) line and remove ; before line start same as remove ; before (;extension=php_intl.dll) in php.ini and save php.ini file.and open xamp manager and stop apache servises and restart again.